# Kotlin: How to send data from RecyclerView adapter to a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm new to Android and new to Kotlin (coming from iOS Swift development). I have an activity that has a fragment, inside the fragment is a RecyclerView. When the user taps on a row in the RecyclerView I want to show a dialog and take some action.

In the adapter I have the CustomViewHolder and onClickListener. From there I can capture the row the user tapped on easily. But how do I pass this information back to the fragment so that I can take action / display a dialog?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using an interface for callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your adapter take a lambda as a parameter...for example

```
class YourAdapter(val listener: (YourDataType) -> Unit)
```

In your view holder you'd then invoke that listener when user clicks on row.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { listener(data) }
```

In your fragment you'd have something like:

```
    yourAdapter = YourAdapter {
        // invoked when user clicks on row
    }
```

Comment: how do you access the "data" in yourAdapter = YourAdapter { } ?

Comment: @kyk yourAdapter = YourAdapter(myDataArray) { doSomethingWith(it) }

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly is it possible to have multiple lambdas, so multiple listener, as adapter parameter?